# How to run all methods of a java applet without specifically calling them?

Tags: java, applet, keyevent

I've just started creating a portal game through applet (yes I know it's totally outdated and I should be using swing blah blah blah), and so far I've only encountered one problem. The browser/appletviewer only calls paint and init automatically. If I want to call a method which needs a keyevent, that can't happen because init doesn't receive anything and paint only receives a Graphic. Therefore I can't call the method thinkerbox, which is kind of important. Here is my code so far (in two classes):

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class portal extends Applet
{

public Image stickA;
public int x = 90;
public int y = 20;

public void init()
{
    stickA = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "stick.jpg" );
}

public void thinkerbox( Graphics screen, KeyEvent e )
{
    addKeyListener(new keyaction());
    keyaction asdf = new keyaction();
    asdf.useKeys( e, screen );
}

public void moveRight( Graphics screen )
{
    addKeyListener(new keyaction());
    screen.setColor( Color.WHITE );
    screen.fillRect( x, y, 100, 100 );
    x += 10;
    paint( screen );
}

public void moveLeft( Graphics screen )
{
    screen.setColor( Color.WHITE );
    screen.fillRect( x, y, 100, 100 );
    x -= 10;
    paint( screen );
}

public void moveUp( Graphics screen )
{
    screen.setColor( Color.WHITE );
    screen.fillRect( x, y, 100, 100 );
    y += 10;
    paint( screen );
}

public void moveDown( Graphics screen )
{
    screen.setColor( Color.WHITE );
    screen.fillRect( x, y, 100, 100 );
    y -= 10;
    paint( screen );
}

public void paint( Graphics screen )
{
    setBackground( Color.WHITE );

    screen.setColor( Color.RED ); 
    screen.fillOval( 20, 20, 40, 80 ); //red portal1
    screen.fillOval( 200, 200, 40, 80 ); //red portal2

    screen.drawImage( stickA, x, y, 100, 100, this );
}
}
```

And the second one:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class keyaction extends KeyAdapter
{

public void useKeys( KeyEvent e, Graphics screen )
{
    int keycode = e.getKeyCode();
    portal p = new portal();

    p.thinkerbox( screen, e );

    if( keycode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT )
    {
        p.moveLeft( screen );
    }
    else if( keycode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT )
    {
        p.moveRight( screen );
    }
    else if( keycode == KeyEvent.VK_UP )
    {
        p.moveUp( screen );
    }
    else if( keycode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN )
    {
        p.moveDown( screen );
    };
}
}
```

Help please?

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:

1. Yes use Swing. You've no reason why not.
2. Use Key Bindings instead of a KeyListener.
3. Call your move methods in your binding actions.
4. Have your these methods change the state of your class -- change the value of one or more of the class fields.
5. Then call `repaint()`
6. Have your drawing JComponent's `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method use the class fields to decide what to draw where.